# Derivative Matrix of function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuously differentiable. Suppose also that $F(0)=0$ and that the derivative matrix $DF(0)$ has the property that there is some positive number $c$ such that $||DF(0)h|| \geq c||h||$ for all $h$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that there is some positive number $r$ such that $||F(h)|| \geq \frac{c}{2} ||h||$ if $||h|| \leq r$

I have no idea how to show this at all.

Comment: This might help: $$F(h)=\int_0^1 DF(th)h\,dt.$$

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need *continuously differentiable*; the derivative at $0$ is all you should look at. Let's write $DF(0)=A$ to shorten formulas. By definition of derivative, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$\|F(h)-Ah\|<\delta \|h\| \quad \text{whenever }\ \|h\|<\delta \tag1$$
It follows (how?) that 
$$\|F(h)\|\ge \|Ah\|-\delta \|h\| \quad \text{whenever }\ \|h\|<\delta \tag2$$
I'll leave it for you to continue the inequality (2) and choose an appropriate $\delta$.